# Is it possible to append indexes modifying initial migration?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using entity framework code first approach in my project. I've created model and enabled migrations using enable-migrations statement in package manager console. My context class contains mapping configurations and relationships like

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PostMap());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());
```

Up method in my migration file 201302261054023_InitialCreate.cs contains all table definitions as my context specified via DbSet<Type> property.

I changed InitializeDatabase method in my custom database Initializer, because I want to migrate up to specific migration during database initialization.

```
public void InitializeDatabase(T context)
{
    bool databaseExists = context.Database.Exists();
    if (!databaseExists)
        context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

    var configuration = new Configuration();
    var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
    migrator.Update("InitialCreate");
}
```

Is possible to modify Up method in 201302261054023_InitialCreate class to add another index from

```
CreateTable(
        "dbo.City",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(maxLength: 450),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

to

```
CreateTable(
        "dbo.City",
         c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(maxLength: 450),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .Index(t=>t.Name,true);
```

without appending another migration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After mining plenty of web pages related to migrations, I've found that modifying initial migration could help me only if I update database to "zero migration" (empty database). Without migration to zero database I could add another migration and create indexes in new migration like

```
public partial class InitialIndexes : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateIndex("City", "Name", true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("City", new[] {"Name"});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an index you can use the ExecuteSqlCommand.

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE INDEX IX_TableName_ColumnName ON TableName (ColumnName)");
```

I normally have this command in a Seed override method like the following.

```
            protected override void Seed(YourContext context)
            {
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE INDEX IX_TableName_ColumnName ON TableName (ColumnName)");
                //...Rest of seed code
             }
```

You should be able to use the same call in your method.

Comment: Gouber, thank you for your answer. My question wasn't described appropriately. I want to manage indexes using migrations. Your approach should be functional, but only in situations when database is migrated to latest version. I need indexes to be created with database migrated to older than latest version.